# How to use symbolic expressions in ODE solvers

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

I need to solve the following symbolic ODE using ode45 function:

```matlab
function ydot=App1(~,y)
% clc;
% clear;
% close all;

syms x [1 4] real;
syms vv [1 2] real;
syms u [1 4] real;

f=sum(x.^2)-2*x(1)-3*x(2);
g1=-x(1);
g2=-x(2);
g3=-x(3);
g4=-x(4);
g=[g1 g2 g3 g4]';
h=[2*x(1)+x(2)+x(3)+4*x(4)-7;
x(1)+x(2)+2*x(3)+x(4)-6];

Psi=[-(gradient(f)+diff(g,'x1').*max(u'+g,0)+...
            diff(g,'x2').*max(u'+g,0)+...
            diff(g,'x3').*max(u'+g,0)+...
            diff(g,'x4').*max(u'+g,0)+...
            gradient(h(1))*vv(1)+...
            gradient(h(2))*vv(2));
            max(u'+g,0)-u';
            h;
            ];

% syms y [1 size(symvar(Psi),2)];
 ydot=subs(Psi,[x1, x2, x3, x4, u1, u2, u3, u4, vv1, vv2],sym('y',[1 10]));
```

I know that I need to convert it into function_handler:

```matlab
aa=matlabFunction(App1);
```

But I don't know how to use in inside the ode45 function:

```matlab
a = unifrnd(-3 , 3 , [1,10]);
[t,y]=ode45(@aa,[0,200],a);
```

MATLAB gives this error:

```matlab
Not enough input arguments.
```

**EDIT:**
My real problem includes **various** functions with many parameters (that should be obtained through ODE45 function) and I'm looking for an automatic way to calculate the gradients and apply them inside the ODE45.

Comment: Unable to run your code at the moment, but it usually fails for this requirement "The function dydt = odefun(t,y), for a scalar t and a column vector y, must return a column vector dydt". What Matlab function generates often is unable to process vector inputs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Looks like you got an interesting question! In order to attract answer, and also to make your question helpful for the rest of the community, please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use [minimal, self-contained examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Good luck.

Comment: Why is your ODE symbolic? At a glance, I don't see why it has a need to be? (Otherwise, pls refers to comment above.)

Comment: Thank you @Argyll, I added some details... I have a complicated function that is not easy to calculate its gradient.

Comment: As in you have another complicated function that is represented by the example in your question? The `f`, `h` in your question are merely quadratic at most. Also, where are the elements of `u` and `vv` defined? In any case, `syms` isn't working properly on my computer. I can't help with that.

Comment: Why a symbolic expression cannot be used in ODE? why ODE is unable to process vector inputs?